# how to avoid duplicate call history details in android

Tags: android, calllog

hi am getting call log details from content Provider it's working fine but output show duplicated call details also how to avoid duplicates in call logs.

current output like

### id name number time

1 abc  1233   2.30 pm

2 bdc  2897    1.pm

3 abc 1233    11.30 am

4 abc 1233    11.00 am

but i don't want this output i need like

### id name number time

1 abc (3) 1233 2.30 pm

2 bdc 2897 1.00 pm

how to achieve this see my code and help me

public void readCallLogs() {

```
    Cursor callLog = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");

    int cid = callLog.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID);

    int cName = callLog.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);

    int cNumber = callLog.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);

    int cType = callLog.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);

    int cDate = callLog.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);

    int cDuration = callLog.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

    // looping call log cursor object
    while (callLog.moveToNext()) {

        String mId = callLog.getString(cid);

        String mName = callLog.getString(cName);
        String mNumber = callLog.getString(cNumber);

        long mCallDate = callLog.getLong(cDate);
```

}

Comment: Hi! Ydder, I am also getting same problem. Will u share the solution that how u solved it... thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the matter of display....
hence once you receive the data you need to apply the filter or you need to write your own code to group the data.

NOTE: you need to be careful while choosing the Data structure (Array, Map). this can hit the performance.